# How to check if my emacsclient is running in a GUI window?

Tags: emacsclient, gui-emacs

Emacs version: 25.3.50.2
I'm using Fira Code font whose ligatures are now supported by Emacs.
To solve this, I used [this solution](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/211) (I think it's not important, just to inform you), say, replacing the ligaturable text with a single large symbol.

However, I use Emacs GUI/Emacs CLI the same often. In CLI, I just have to configure the console's font. Since I use Konsole which supports ligature, I should do nothing with my Emacs. In GUI, I have to do the replacing job.

The solution mentioned above used this code:

```
;;; Fira code
;; This works when using emacs --daemon + emacsclient
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions (lambda (frame) (set-fontset-font t '(#Xe100 . #Xe16f) "Fira Code Symbol")))
;; This works when using emacs without server/client
(set-fontset-font t '(#Xe100 . #Xe16f) "Fira Code Symbol")
;; I haven't found one statement that makes both of the above situations work, so I use both for now
```

But if I'm using emacsclient in CLI, it still replace the symbols, and my console connot display those weired symbols (of course!).
That is to say, the code above will work when I'm using Emacs GUI, and 
 emacsclient in both GUI and CLI.

What I want is, to prevent it from working when using emacsclient+CLI.

What can I do?

### Conclusion for impatient answerers

I want to run some elisp code only when using emacsclient with GUI. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're not *using* the `frame` argument which is passed to `after-make-frame-functions`.

Try something like this:

```el
;; Per-frame/terminal configuration.
(defun my-frame-behaviours (&optional frame)
  "Make frame- and/or terminal-local changes."
  (with-selected-frame (or frame (selected-frame))
    (when window-system
      ;; Fira code for GUI Emacs frames.
      (set-fontset-font t '(#Xe100 . #Xe16f) "Fira Code Symbol" frame))))
;; Run now, for non-daemon Emacs...
(my-frame-behaviours)
;; ...and later, for new frames / emacsclient
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-frame-behaviours)
```

As per glucas's answer, you may want to replace the `window-system` test with some `display-*-p` predicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `display-graphic-p`.  See [Display Feature Testing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Feature-Testing.html#Display-Feature-Testing) in the Emacs manual, there are a bunch of other `display-*-p` predicates for checking what display capabilities are available.

Comment: Can you check my code with `emacsclient`? Seems that it doesn't work at all. I've added your code there, but it still doesn't work (in emacsclient + gui, still no ligatures)